# Flake8 Not Recognizing built-in exception

Tags: python, githooks, flake8

I have a strict pre-commit hook set up with flake8, so I can't commit until its happy. This is normally a good thing, but it is causing some problems with what seems like no problem at all.

I can't get Flake8 to recognize a `FileNotFoundError`.

**example.py**

```
try:
    pass
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

This is enough code to get Flake8 to generate the error

```
$ flake8 example.py
example.py:3:8: F821 undefined name 'FileNotFoundError'
$ python example.py # no error
$ python3 example.py # no error
```

I checked the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError), and FileNotFoundError is a 'built-in' exception, so I don't think I should have to import it from anywhere, and my python interpreters have not complained about it, just seems like an issue with flake8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running python `2.7.8` I get the follwoing:

```
 except FileNotFoundError:
 NameError: name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined
```

If I change to `OSError` it works correctly  on `python 3`

```
except OSError:
```

[FileNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) is a subclass of `OSError` in `python3`

Using `OSError` will catch more than just the `FileNotFound` error in python 3 so you may want to add additional checks.

For `python 2` it is an `IOError`:

You can catch the specific error:

```
import __builtin__

exc = getattr(__builtin__,"IOError","FileNotFoundError")

try:
    (open("bad_file"))
except exc:
    pass
```

Sure there are betters ways but for python 3:

```
try:
    f = (open("bad_file"))
except OSError as e:
    if isinstance(e, FileNotFoundError):
        pass
    else:
        raise e
```

Comment: I don't get that error in `2.7.6`, but I suppose I can change to OSError.

Comment: @NateMara, it is IOError in python 2 but OSError for python 3

Comment: This is a pyflakes question, not a question about implementation details.

I think that the root cause of the OP's problem is mostly likely that pyflakes was running under python 2. See the comment from @Bryce below for what is probably a more fitting solution.

Comment: Rewriting a code in such cases - not a good idea. You should provide a proper configuration for `flake8` . @Bryce answer is a better choice for this case

Answer (score 23):

I found a couple of mentions of this issue on the [Python Code Quality](https://gitlab.com/groups/pycqa) tools repo. Specifically [Issue #75](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/75).

Two workarounds were listed. You can use the `--builtins` flag to specify a comma separated list of known builtins that flake8 is flagging.

```
$ flake8 example.py
example.py:3:8: F821 undefined name 'FileNotFoundError'
$ flake8 --builtins=FileNotFoundError,... example.py
$
```

The other workaround is running flake8 under python3 instead of python2.

```
$ /usr/bin/python3.5 -m pyflakes example.py 
$
```

Hopefully one of these two solutions will work out for you, as twisting your code up to work around a syntax check tool is counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bryce's answer, another option which avoids contorting the code to fit the syntax check tool, is to add a `noqa` flag to the relevant line:

```
try:
    open("bad_file")
except FileNotFoundError: # noqa: F821
    print("file not found")
```

This just tells flake8 to ignore this particular error on this particular line.